# Java I don't understand why I get different outputs when I change the order of my switch statements

Tags: java

When I write:

```
System.out.println("[move,new,restart,hint,solve,quit]>");
            String input = in.next();
            switch (input){
                case "restart":
                    System.out.println("You chose restart");
                    continue;
                case "quit"://Quits out of the program
                    cont = false;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("here");
```

I get the output:

```
[move,new,restart,hint,solve,quit]>
restart
You chose restart
[move,new,restart,hint,solve,quit]>
quit
here
```

But when I switch the case statements for restart and quit I recieve a different output:
What I code:

```
System.out.println("[move,new,restart,hint,solve,quit]>");
            String input = in.next();
            switch (input){
                case "quit"://Quits out of the program
                    cont = false;
                case "restart":
                    System.out.println("You chose restart");
                    continue;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("here");
```

I get the output:

```
[move,new,restart,hint,solve,quit]>
restart
You chose restart
[move,new,restart,hint,solve,quit]>
quit
You chose restart
```

I am having a difficult time understanding why the sequence of the case statements affects the output.

Comment: Time to use a debugger.

Comment: Heard about `break` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your case is missing a `break;` for your "quit" logic

```
switch (input){
            case "quit"://Quits out of the program
                cont = false;
                break;
            case "restart":
                System.out.println("You chose restart");
                continue;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
case "quit"://Quits out of the program
                    cont = false;
```

Here you don't have a break or continue. Therefore if that matches all below ones will also get executed